# text having newlines not downloading perfectly in csv file

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, csv

I have data in a database that needs to be exported to CSV. Some of the fields include newlines which **MUST** be preserved.I am using sed to export data and it is being exported like this (this is sample data of course):

```
38,"testing 
here"
```

in csv file after download it is showing as:

[image: csv file output]

but it should download like:

[image: expected output]

Following command using to download csv file:

```
mysql -r -u*** -p*** -P*** -h****   databaseName -e 'call procedurename (0,38,10)' | sed 's/\t/,/g' > /sample.csv
```

Is it possible to export newlines in CSV files? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't be shy show us your code and sample data.

Comment: CSV does not support multiline values. Replace linebreaks with some predefined literal (`\n`, for example) before exporting, and revert during/after the import.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: tried replacing \r\n with \n still no use